# How to close IMAP APPEND command from a openssl connection

Tags: macos, java-me, terminal, imap

I would like to know how to close an APPEND command from the Unix Terminal. My goal is to create a Draft message on the Gmail IMAP server from the Mac Terminal or with JavaME. I've used the follow commands so far:

> openssl s_client -crlf -connect imap.gmail.com:993
>   ...
>   A1 LOGIN myaccount@gmail.com mypassword
>   ...
>   A2 SELECT "[Gmail]/Drafts"
>   ...
>   A3 APPEND "[Gmail]/Drafts" (\Seen) {310}
>   + go ahead
>   Date: Fri, 29 Apr 2011 10:00:00 -0800 (PST)
>   ...
>   Content-Type: TEXT-PLAIN; CHARSET=US-ASCII
>
> Message Body

I tried to send a CRLF (\r\n) by using  a socket connection and the Control+V, return, return in the Terminal.

Comment: {310} is the exact number of message characters, include the carriage return and line feed. It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

{310} is the exactly number of message characters, including the carriage return and line feed, it worked fine.

Comment: It would be great if you could clarify your question/answer. It's not obvious what you achieved and how.